# JWT token expiration not working in Asp.Net Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, jwt

I  have set the token expiry to 1 minute, but I am not getting the 401 unauthorized error after 1 minute.

**Startup.cs**

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });
```

**Token Generation method:**

```
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
int expiryMins = 1
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
  _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
  null,
  expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryMins),
  signingCredentials: credentials);

return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: Is it using the token otherwise?  If the token isn't sent in the header does it 401?

Comment: By default the authentication handler allows for some clock skew to account for clocks being different on servers. IIRC it's 5 minutes and can be adjusted in TokenValidationParameters.

Comment: @possum yes, its using the token,

Comment: @juunas what does it mean?

Comment: It means this line `ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),`.

Comment: ClockSkew means that if it is set to 5 minutes, the token will work 5 minutes after it has expired. It's usually a good idea to leave it like this since server times could be different.

Comment: @juunas it worked, please add as answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, this was due to the clock skew setting defaulting to 5 minutes, allowing tokens to be considered valid max 5 minutes after expiry (from the server's point of view that validates the token).
Clock skew setting exists because the server that issues the token and the server that validates the token might have slight differences in their clocks.
Usually it is a good idea to have some flexibility here and the default of 5 minutes is okay.
If you do not wish to have this behaviour, you can set ClockSkew on the TokenValidationParameters to 0 seconds.